# Blurry WooCommerce Product Images

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I’m setting up a Woocommerce store and all the product images are blurry.

I suspect it’s the issue described in this article: docs.woocommerce.com/document/fixing-blurry-product-images
“Your image dimensions should match or be higher than those of your theme.”

The original image sizes are definitely large enough.

I tried to implement the solution from the article above, but I’m having trouble fixing the problem in the new in Appearance > Customise > WooCommerce > Product Images.

I've tried everything I could find, but nothing seems to be working.

We use Verdure - Organic Tea Shop Theme and WooCommerce version 5.1.0.

The images look completely fine on mobile.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post screenshots?

Comment: This sounds like an end-user problem with general purpose software, not a programming question. I'd suggest taking it to [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or a dedicated forum for this product.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe *Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Images* is not the place you need to look, your theme probably overrides this. Instead of looking for image size settings in *Appearance > Customize*, try looking if your theme has a custom Appearance settings panel. [It seems like it does!](https://verdure.qodeinteractive.com/documentation/#mikado_options)